# exclude images with a specific class in jpreloader

Tags: jquery, jpreloader

How do I exclude all images with class 'lazy' in jpreloader?

This is my code... it's same this http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/js/jpreloader.js
and demo page
http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/

```
//get all images from css and <img> tag
var getImages = function(element) {
    $(element).find('*:not(script)').each(function() {
        var url = "";

        if ($(this).css('background-image').indexOf('none') == -1 && $(this).css('background-image').indexOf('-gradient') == -1) {
            url = $(this).css('background-image');
            if(url.indexOf('url') != -1) {
                var temp = url.match(/url\((.*?)\)/);
                url = temp[1].replace(/\"/g, '');
            }
        } else if ($(this).get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img' && typeof($(this).attr('src')) != 'undefined') {
            url = $(this).attr('src');
        }

        if (url.length > 0) {
            items.push(url);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you share some html code?? it will be easy to help you the.

Comment: the js file is this view-source:http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/js/jpreloader.js      my code html                                                                cicle for ......<img class="lazy" data-src="photo/<?php echo $nome; ?>"  src="gfx/loading.gif" /></a>..... <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.lazy').jail({
     triggerElement : '#cont',
     event : 'scroll',
     timeout : 100
    });
   });
  </script>

Comment: @MarcelloViolini, don't add html in a comment! Click on 'edit' at the bottom of your question and add the html there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for but isn't it enough:

```
$(element).find('*:not(script):not(.lazy)').each(function() {...})
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work
it is possible not to load images lazy with class?
how can I "hide them" ? thx

Comment: Everything is possible! I still don't know what you are exactly looking for. BTW, "unfortunately does not work " doesn't help me (you) so much. Could you provide a link to sample website? Maybe set a jsfiddle.

Comment: this is the code example http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/js/jpreloader.js  and this the example http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/                                            code preload the images from my site (and img src)
I have to exclude the loading of all the image they have as a class "lazy"